# Function return value vs. invocation - what should happen?

Tags: vb.net

suppose I have two overloads like this:

```
Public Function MyTest(i As Integer) As SomeType
    classField_i = i
    Return MyTest
End Function

Public Function MyTest As SomeType
    Return New SomeType()
End Function
```

what I would expect in calling the first overload is an instance of SomeType, however, what I get is Nothing.  The reason seems to be that instead of invoking the niladic overload, the compiler opts to evaluate the internally declared variable `MyTest`, which has not been set.

so that suggests I should declare the first function like this:

```
Public Function MyTest(i As Integer) As SomeType
    classField_i = i
    Return MyTest()
End Function
```

but in VB.Net, parentheses for function calls are not required!  so this seems like an odd anomaly where the compiler resolves the ambiguity in an unexpected manner.

what are good reasons for which the behaviour is what it is?

*** Edit I ***

in my original post I had specified Integer as the return value for the function, which as Plutonix pointed out could never return a Nothing.  I fixed it to return an object of SomeType as it is in the real code

Comment: you have something else going on if a Function declared `As Integer` is returning Nothing.

Comment: The first function isn't doing anything in respect to the return vairable. You set `classField_i` equal to `i` but then you return an uninitialized variable, `MyTest`. The problem is the scope of the `MyTest` in the first function; it's no longer the name of a function but rather a private variable to that function.

Comment: @Plutonix, my bad.  in creating the example I just picked Integer but in the working code it returns an object.  I will fix the post.  thank you

Comment: see the answer from the_lotus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside functions, VB uses the function name as a variable for return value.

Instead of

```
Public Function MyTest As Integer
    Return 3
End Function
```

You could write

```
Public Function MyTest() As Integer
    MyTest = 3
End Function
```

In your function, you are actually returning that variable and not calling a function. Try this, you might understand what is happening.

```
Public Function MyTest(ByVal i As Integer) As Integer
    MyTest = 4
    Return MyTest
End Function
```

Don't take any chances and always use () when calling a sub or function.

If you really want to omit the () then use Me. Since the local variable take precedent to any declaration in a class when they have the same name.

```
Public Function MyTest(i As Integer) As Integer
    classField_i = i
    Return Me.MyTest
End Function
```

Comment: I know there is an internally declared variable with the same name as the function.  I stated so in my post.  my question relates to why the designers of the compiler chose this method of disambiguation, creating a special case that developers would have to know and remember, instead of the more natural choice which was to consider it an overload invocation, since one is available.  if no niladic overload were available I would say it makes total sense to return the value of the internal variable

Comment: @ekkis the variable with the same name as the function comes from the old VB6 specification. The creator of .NET migrated this behavior to support legacy system. Local variable take precedent to what ever is declared in the class. Like anything else, if you want to access something in the class that has the same name as something in your function, you need to use Me. Just do: Return Me.MyTest  I'll add it do the answer.

Comment: ah.  that makes perfect sense.  thank you so much for that last bit.  I can live with that